# Determine order of (p,d,q) & (P,D,Q,s) in SARIMAX Python

Tags: python, time-series, pyramid-arima

I am trying to build SARIMAX model, trying to determine the (p,d,q) & (P,D,Q,s) values from ACF, PACF plots. My series is stationary without any differencing being required (based on ADF test). While I understand from PACF plot that p=2 & q=2 (though ACF is decaying exponentially, I believe it could be due to cumulative effect of lags on each other) should be good enough, I am slightly confused as to how I can arrive at the P,Q values for the seasonal part. My data is daily observations collected for about 4 years. From the below seasonal part of the decomposition, I could see that pattern repeats itself for every 7 days. Here is the ACF, PACF plots for the undifferenced original data.

Appreciate your guidance in helping me identify the P,Q values for the seasonal part of the series.

[ACF PACF Plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7UuI1.png)

[Seasonal Component](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9CojI.png)

Answer (score 0):

Did you check auto_arima function which you can import from pmdarima package. If you are sure about the seasonal frequency, declaring it in auto_arima function would be enough to find the parameters.